# Send message from content script to background script in a chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to receive a message from my content in my background script from a context menu onclick event. Here's the content script:

```
var clickedEl = null;

document.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event){
    if(event.button == 2) { 
        clickedEl = event.target;
        console.log("event.target = "+event.target);
    }
}, true);

chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(request == "getClickedEl") {
        console.log("requestValue = " + clickedEl);
        sendResponse({value: clickedEl.value});
    }
});
```

Here's my background script where I send the message to the content script when the context menu is clicked.

```
function doScripts(context, targ){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code: "var doingBrowserAction = "+(context)+"; var contextTarg = "+(targ)+";"}, function(){
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "js/myscript.js"}, function(){});
    });
}

function getClickHandler(info, tab) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, "getClickedEl", function(clickedEl) {
        var currTarg = clickedEl.value;
        doScripts(false, currTarg);
    });
}

chrome.contextMenus.create({
    "title" : "DESTROY!",
    "type" : "normal",
    "contexts" : ["page","selection","link","editable","image","video","audio"],
    "onclick" : getClickHandler
});
```

I'm confirming that the onMessage is being called from the background script with

```
console.log("requestValue = " + clickedEl);
```

in the `onMessage` listener, and that's working.  My main problem is when I get the variable on the background script it comes out as null, and when I try to pass the variable to the `doScripts` function it doesn't work.  I think I'm having a problem on the receiving end by the way I'm parsing the message, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [pass dom element from background script to chrome.tabs.executeScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18387784/pass-dom-element-from-background-script-to-chrome-tabs-executescript)

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions. There's an "Edit" link at the bottom of the question if you want to add more information.